# ReactJS application taking a long time for MP4 download in browser

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, networking, video-streaming, mp4

I am working on a react application which is using `react-player` library to load an MP4 video.

On the video some labelling has to be done,  which calls a streaming API which reads the video content in a given range from a video uploaded in S3. Now when the frontend calls this API with some parameters for the video like time range etc. the API call gives a 206 response within < 1s, but as seen from network tab the content download is taking ~ 6 seconds. I've tried to read a lot of posts online and tried to diagnose using network tab and logs, but no help. Requesting support as I've been stuck on this for a long time.

#### Environment

- **Front-end:** React (using the React Player library)
- **Back-end:** Java
- **Video Source:** AWS S3
- **API:** Custom GetMedia API

#### Workflow and Issue

Our application allows users to annotate video frames with bounding boxes.

The typical workflow involves:

- Pausing the video.
- Drawing a bounding box on the current frame.
- Moving to the next frame (or skipping 10 frames ahead) using a 'next' button.
- Repeating the annotation process for subsequent frames.
- After repeating this process for around 100 frames (or 10 cycles of 10 frames), when trying to navigate back or change frames, the loading becomes exceedingly slow.

#### API Details

- **API Call:** GetMedia (custom streaming API).
- **Parameters:** MediaID, User, UriInfo, AuthToken, TransitiveAuthToken, MediaContentType, Range.
- **Data Source:** Media content is fetched from S3.

#### Observations

- The issue is primarily observed after the bounding box annotation process only for certain videos and that too of length > 2 min.
- Delays are notable in 'content download'. Increasing exponentially upto > 10s.
- There is not delay in shift of bounding boxes if I move to an older already annotated frame. The delay is only in video switching back to that frame.

#### Attempted Solutions

- Monitored memory and resource usage without identifying any leaks or excessive usage.

#### Screenshots

[image: ContentDownloadInNetworkTab]

[image: PerformanceTabShowingNormalCPUUsage]

[image: SummaryOfDelayCausingNetworkRequest]

Comment: The correct tag for your Question is `mp4` but I know they will close this one in 5 seconds flat because there is not enough testable details to give an Answer. It's possible that your _"Custom GetMedia API"_ is the slow part. Can you provide a testable URL to one of your `test.mp4` file? It will be faster to analyze than guessing what is the problem... But a good guess is that your MP4 has its metadata (telling which bytes are which frames) put at the back of file, so GetMedia must download the full 9MB just to reach the metadata, then it has to create a new output MP4 based on your range.